# Attribute names in table in the form varchar2

Tags: select, plsql, attributes, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hey I'm studying Object oriented databases and I came across this question , ' User will input name of the attribute name( X ) and and the value of the attribute (Y ) and you have to do following...
       `select * from table where X = Y` 
How to achieve this ?

Comment: You will probably need dynamic SQL for this if the column name is not fixed and known.

Comment: Hey thanks, i solved it using [dynamic sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

Comment: Note you can pass `Y` as a bind variable.

Comment: What do you mean by bind variable ?

Answer (score 0):

From sqlplus you can do a simple `&`

```
SQL> select * from table where x='&y' ;

Enter value for y: 12
old   1: select * from table where x='&y'
old   1: select * from table where x='12'
....
```

Then if you want it in plsql, then here's how to [*bind* variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch34.htm):

```
-- declare variable
VARIABLE y varchar2(10);

-- assign its value
begin
   :y := 'Y';
end;
/

-- use it in your procedure
declare
  v_r number :=0;
begin
  select count(1) from "table" where x like ('%'||:y||'%');
  dbms_output.put_line('found:'||v_r);

  -- you can also change bind variable value
  :y := :y||':'||v_r;
end;
/

-- print value
print y
```

Launched from a script file in sqlplus (with @):

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

found:1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Q:1
```